# Group by two columns and calculate percent using two different subsets of data in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a solution but keep getting stuck.

I have a dataframe that contains four columns `ID` `group` `type` `value`. I would like to group the records by `group, value` and calculate a percentage based on the values in the `type` column. Only two values can exist in this column (`numer`, `denom`).

My data looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E'],
                   'group': ['red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue'],
                   'type': ['numer', 'denom', 'numer', 'denom', 'numer', 'denom', 'numer', 'denom', 'numer', 'denom',
                            'denom'],
                   'value': ['1', '1', '0', 'NaN', '2', '2', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2']
                   })
# df
   ID  group   type value
0   A    red  numer     1
1   A    red  denom     1
2   B    red  numer     0
3   B    red  denom   NaN
4   C  green  numer     2
5   C  green  denom     2
6   D   blue  numer     1
7   D   blue  denom     1
8   D   blue  numer     2
9   D   blue  denom     2
10  E   blue  denom     2
```

I would like to divide the counts of `numer` by the counts of `denom` for each grouped pair (`group, value`) so the final result would look something like this:

```
group  value  percent
red        0      0.0
           1      1.0
           2      0.0
         NaN      0.0
green      0      0.0
           1      0.0
           2      1.0
         NaN      0.0     
blue       0      0.0
           1      1.0
           2      0.5
         NaN      0.0
```

So far, I've been trying to apply a similar approach to this as I would in SQL using Window functions. My current code doesn't calculate the values as I want using (counts of numer / counts of denom).  Instead it computes the percentages based on the subtotals in each grouped pair:

```
res = df.groupby(['group','value']).agg({'ID': 'count'})
pct_df = res.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 100 * x / float(x.sum()))

#pct_df
               ID
group value      
blue  1      0.40
      2      0.60
green 2      1.00
red   0      0.25
      1      0.50
      NaN    0.25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas `.pivot_table()`

```
d = df.pivot_table('ID', ['group', 'value'], 'type', 'count').assign(val=lambda d:d['numer']/d['denom'])

print(d)
```

```
type         denom  numer  val
group value                   
blue  1        1.0    1.0  1.0
      2        2.0    1.0  0.5
green 2        1.0    1.0  1.0
red   0        NaN    1.0  NaN
      1        1.0    1.0  1.0
      NaN      1.0    NaN  NaN
```

Or, pandas `.groupby()` with `.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().to_dict().get(<denom / numer> , np.nan)`. This basically converts the `value_counts` result to dictionary and using the `.get` method on a dictionary you retrieve the value (or `np. nan` if it doesn't exist in the dictionary)

```
df.groupby(['group','value'])['type'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().to_dict().get('numer', np.nan) / x.value_counts().to_dict().get('denom', np.nan))
```

```
group  value
blue   1        1.0
       2        0.5
green  2        1.0
red    0        NaN
       1        1.0
       NaN      NaN
Name: type, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` after groupby then reindex the multiindex to generate the index you want.

You could also try [`Series.values_count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).

```py
def division(numer, denom):
    return numer / denom if denom else 0

res = df.groupby(['group','value'])['type'].apply(lambda col: division(sum(col.eq('numer')), sum(col.eq('denom')))).to_frame('percent')

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['group'].unique(), sorted(df['value'].unique())], names=res.index.names)

res = res.reindex(index, fill_value=0)
```

```
print(res)

             percent
group value         
red   0          0.0
      1          1.0
      2          0.0
      NaN        0.0
green 0          0.0
      1          0.0
      2          1.0
      NaN        0.0
blue  0          0.0
      1          1.0
      2          0.5
      NaN        0.0
```